# c# webApi reaching null data when posting from Angular 2 client

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I've set up a Angular 2 client and a C#.NET Core WebApi to comunicate between them. When I send POST data from the client, it is reaching as null value in the server. The controller being called is;

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody] string descr) // descr aways null
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(descr))
        {
            try
            {
                Restaurante novo = new Restaurante(descr);
                cnx.Restaurantes.Add(novo);
                cnx.SaveChanges();
                return Ok(novo);
            }
            catch
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        } else return BadRequest();

    }
```

The part of the client that generates the JSon data:

```
postRestauranteHttp(nome: string) : Observable<IRestaurante>{

    console.log("nome: " + nome);
    let body = JSON.stringify({ 'descr' : nome });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post("http://address/to/api" , body, options)
    .map((response: Response) => <IRestaurante>response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Try this first: remove `this` from in front of the `this.options` in your post call. Like this: `return this._http.post("http://address/to/api" , body, options)`.

Comment: my bad, that "this" is not there anymore, i'll edit my post

Comment: - 1-First check if the json are properly formatted before send it to controller, otherwise its not possible for api controller recognize it.

 - 2-From your code, you are receiving it as string and your client are passing it as json format.

Comment: @FábioNevesRezende you need to concatenate with 'xxx ' before and after the body, to send it as string or change the controller to receive as you want.

Answer (score 0):

- **1**-First check if the json are properly formatted before send it to controller, otherwise its not possible for api controller
  recognize it.
- **2**-From your code, you are receiving it as string and your client are passing it as json format.
- **3**-You need to concatenate with ' ' before and after the body, to send it as string or change the controller to receive as you want.